# Web Scraping : To extract data from a shopping website whose classes are different using BeautifulSoul in Python

Tags: python, class, web-scraping

I’m very new to Web Scraping so looking out for some help.
So basically these classes contain a bunch of product lists that I want to extract. But inspite having same initial class name A some have an additional name further as “animate” or “noOffer”. This pattern occurs more than 200-300 times and is random for each product, so I would really like to automate the extraction.

Problem is when I try extracting the data of first 100 products there’s this mixture of class names.
I have been able to put a for loop and findAll to extract data from either 1 of those classes. I need a way to append the data to a list which contain a mixture of all these 3 classes

Ultimately I want to create a CSV, from panda DataFrame.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please improve your question, so that we can reproduce your issue. How to create [mcve] Thanks

Comment: Post the URL and what are your trying to scrape from it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.